# How to create a dynamic table (Word, Dynamics CRM) to offer the customer?

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I must design dynamically created table from offer to the client. In the offers a variable number of products so the my table must dynamically create rows with products.

For example:
When the offer include 3 products then the table must have 3 rows with this products.
When the offer include 2 products then the table must have 2 rows with this products.

I can do only a table with static number of rows. When I create table with 2 rows I must add only two products because more than two will not be visible.

Can I do something like that in Word and use as template in CRM Online? Can do this without programming? Or I must use some custom solution and add to CRM?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but, it sounds like you have:

1. Two entities - Offer and Product
2. An Offer can be many Products - linked via a relationship, probably Many-to-Many.

I don't think you will be able to use the Templates because they wont allow you to get data from relationships as you have them, as far as I know.

I think in this case the most workable solution will be a Fetch-Xml (because of Crm Online) Based SSRS Report (so you can have a custom layout) as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328302.aspx

Then users just have to run the report against a particular offer, save, print and send.

Comment: Thanks James for your respond. But I can use this data to put them into Template - when I have manually create Offer in Word after I import data from CRM. 
I have mean something like that: [DocumentsWizard_for_CRM_2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9lsiWOzee0&feature=relmfu)

Comment: That a bespoke peice of work - thats not included with Crm. So you would either have to buy it from the creator or make your own. If you cant do that, using a report as I suggested above is probably the best decision.